# how to routing by onclick with variable in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I am trying to pass variable from this tr tag to another page

```
 <tr  onclick="document.location = 'edits/'+this.id" id="<?php echo  $user->id ?>"  class="gradeX">
              <td><?php echo  $user->id ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $user->username ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $user->email ?></td>
            </tr>
```

and this is my route

```
Route::get('/edits/{ids}', function($ids){

    return view('edits', [
      'userID'=> $ids
    ]);

} );
```

It works. But the problem is that the page appears without style.

Is my way wrong?
Is there a way to correct it?

Any help i will be grateful

Comment: Check dev console in your chrome browser for the possible errors.

Comment: this is my dev console look in picture
https://i.imgsafe.org/5cad56eee7.jpg

Comment: It's clear that your routes for `.css` are 404. Please check your routes for assets resource or show your code where you use those assets in view.

Comment: i put these files in public folder 

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorpicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uniform.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/matrix-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/matrix-media.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" />`

Comment: Please edit your question with these changes. An image in comments will help nobody in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) helper function to generate a URL for an application asset as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
```

Remember you have to put all your assets in `app/public` folder and to access them from your views you can use `asset()` helper method.

Comment: no thing works, when i do what you say i have this error


      `Call to undefined function assest()`

Comment: Ok my mistake, there was a typo it's `asset()` not `assest()`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: looks like already answered, but i encourage OP to read [this documentation on blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade) and [the docs on helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers) so, things done in laravel's way.